# how to get the drop down text value in to label.text

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu

I am using this  [**ZHDropDownMenuDelegate**](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=zh-CN&u=https://github.com/zhubch/DropDownMenu&usg=ALkJrhhg0nzKxg9jaOto7UgNtb4dx6BImA) library for my drop down list option. Now i have two many drop down options. For example i have drop down for country,state.Here below example code :

```
Emenu1.options = ["1","2","3"]

    Emenu2.options = ["1a","2b","3c"]
```

Now using this two method function i can get the which drop down option i have selected :

```
     func dropDownMenu(menu: ZHDropDownMenu!, didChoose index: Int) {
            print("\(menu) choosed at index \(index)")

            let country : NSString = Emenu1.options .objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString

           ECountryInputName.text = country as String



            let secondmenu : NSString = Emenu2.options .objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString

              IamInputName.text! = secondmenu as String!

            print(IamInputName.text)

}


//编辑完成后回调
    func dropDownMenu(menu: ZHDropDownMenu!, didInput text: String!) {
        // print("\(menu) input text \(text)")
    }
```

So in first menu if i select `1` then in my second menu its automatically selecting `1a`.

If i select `2a` in my second menu, then in first menu`2` is automatically selecting.

Now how can i select my option seperately without using index value.Please help me out !!

Thanks

Comment: You need to check for which `menu` you are choosing in `didChoose` method. You might have to set `tag` for each `ZHDropDownMenu` and then compare it in the `didChoose` method.

Comment: i am new to ios,  know to set tag values. For example for first menu = 10, second menu = 20. Can you please give me some code snip of how can i compare. Because in this library its very difficult for me to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `tag` in your `storyboard` for each `menu (ZHDropDownMenu)` and then do below:

```
func dropDownMenu(menu: ZHDropDownMenu!, didChoose index: Int) {        
    if menu.tag == 0 {
        let country : NSString = Emenu1.options .objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString
        ECountryInputName.text = country as String
    }else if menu.tag == 1 {
        let secondmenu : NSString = Emenu2.options .objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString
        IamInputName.text! = secondmenu as String!
    }
}
```

And please avoid using `!`s, it is kind of inviting your app to crash at some point.
[image]

Comment: That optional , i need to remove for all place or for any paticular part ??

Comment: Thanks a lot for easy way.